# Terminal object in a Cartesian Closed Category

Tags: category-theory, higher-order-logic, cartesian-closed-categories

Pierce's [Basic Category Theory for Computer Scientists](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/basic-category-theory-computer-scientists) writes:

> 1.10.2 Definition A Cartesian Closed Category (CCC) is a category with a terminal object, binary products and exponentiation.

I recall that a Cartesian Closed Category has something to do with higher order logic. What is the terminal object there?

Comment: Can you specify the question? The terminal object is the identity element for the direct product operation, and is most often a singleton set in concrete categories.

Comment: I don't know more about Cartesian Closed Categories, an educated category theorist might be able to list some CCCs and name their terminal objects, especially for a CCC that is a construction from higher order logic.